# Transforming Multiindex into single index after groupby() Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Probably this question is a bundle of some functions. I am having trouble renaming multiple index and transforming into simple index.

Lets say I have the following DF

```
Customer      Date               Amount
John          10-10-2016         100,00
Mark          12-10-2016         50,00
John          13_10_2016         200,00
```

If I apply the following code:

```
aggregation = {'Amount':{
                'total' : 'sum'},
                'Date':{
                 'first_purchase' :'min',
                 'last_purchase' : 'max'}
               }
 df_final = df.groupby('Customer').agg(aggregation).reset_index()
```

The result I get is:

```
  Customer     Amount           Date
               total            first_purchase    last_purchase 
  John         300,00            10-10-2016       13-10_2016
  Mark         50,00             12-10-2016       12-10-2016
```

The thing is, I will use this dataframe later to merge with others and the multiindex is not good for me. I wanto to turn it into a single index to have a dataframe like this:

```
      Customer     total            first_purchase    last_purchase 
      John         300,00            10-10-2016       13-10_2016
      Mark         50,00             12-10-2016       12-10-2016
```

I have already tried some unstack and reset index to level 0 but it does not work. Can anyone help me with that? I am sorry if it is a repeated question but I have not found the answer so far after trying many times.

tks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can using `droplevel`

```
df_final.columns=df_final.columns.droplevel(0)
df_final.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Comment: If I do this I lose the "customer" column. But I can rename it later. Tks for the answer

Comment: Now I got it. forget the comment above. To make it work I hjust need to drop the reset_index() in my code:  df.groupby('Customer').agg(aggregation).reset_index(). Then it works.